# How is openssl 1.1.1 EOL going to affect boringssl / netty-tcnative-boringssl-static?

Tags: netty, boringssl

My project relies on netty-tcnative-boringssl-static for memory efficiency.  From what I can tell, boringssl was forked from openssl 1.1.1, which is soon reaching end of life.  I'd like to know how this might affect boringssl, and transitively netty-tcnative-boringssl-static.  Can I expect boringssl / netty-tcnative-boringssl-static to continue with security patches?

Hoping that someone from Google's boringssl team can provide some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While BoringSSL aims to have OpenSSL 1.1.1 compatibility, it is regularly receiving updates. Therefore the OpenSSL 1.1.1 end of life means nothing for BoringSSL. As for netty-tcnative, it updates its version of BoringSSL each time a new version is released (pulling in the latest chromium-stable BoringSSL branch -- [docs](https://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html#boringssl)). At the time of this writing, the chromium-stable branch was last updated in Feb 2023 so it is consistently receiving updates.

[image]

As long as you are staying up to date with netty releases, you shouldn't have to worry about OpenSSL 1.1.1's end of life.