# openssl 1.1.1/1.0.2 EOL impact on netty-tcnative-boringssl-static

Tags: openssl, netty, boringssl

I am using netty-tcnative-boringssl-static <2.0.34.Final> with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips.
Now I am planning to upgrade OpenSSL to 3.x version as part of security upgrade. I have a few questions:

- What would be the impact of this upgrade?
- Would everything work as usual for the current version of netty-tcnative-boringssl-static?
- How to know netty-tcnative-boringssl-static is based(forked) out of which OpenSSL version?
- Do I need to upgrade netty-tcnative-boringssl-static to be compatible with OpenSSL 3.x ?

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how you are using OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips? netty-tcnative-boringssl-static uses the chromium-stable BoringSSL branch, so I'm skeptical that you are using OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips.  
  
Netty's BoringSSL version is consistently updated (as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270687/how-is-openssl-1-1-1-eol-going-to-affect-boringssl-netty-tcnative-boringssl-st/76443591#76443591), but it won't make your application OpenSSL 3.x compatible. OpenSSL v3 and BoringSSL have largely the same API, but I don't believe BoringSSL is guaranteeing any OpenSSL v3 specific support.

Comment: @ddelnano You are correct. After doing more analysis I found out that, OpenSSL is just present in the container, we are infact using boringSSL as part of netty-tcnative-boringssl-static.

Answer (score 0):

While BoringSSL is OpenSSL API compatible, you can think of them as different projects when it comes to security updates. BoringSSL is constantly receiving updates and netty-tcnative is pulling those updates in. See my answer on [How is openssl 1.1.1 EOL going to affect boringssl / netty-tcnative-boringssl-static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270687/how-is-openssl-1-1-1-eol-going-to-affect-boringssl-netty-tcnative-boringssl-st/76443591#76443591) for more details.

As far as I'm aware, BoringSSL is not doing anything in response to OpenSSL's v3 development. It is still largely API compatible for the common interfaces.